# How do I add unique object IDs to an existing C# application?

Tags: c#, ios, uniqueidentifier

I want to add unique object identifiers to an existing C# application. The application is developed to run on ios. Is there a way to access object properties in Visual Studio/Xamarin and add an identifier to each  object OR any other best way to do this. Please advise, Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for an identifier aside from the ID field?

Comment: Do you mean any instance of any object or just some particular class in your app?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are talking about.  What does it mean to "add an identifier to each object"?  You mean like if C# were Javascript and you were dynamically setting a (non-existant) property to any random object?

Answer (score 0):

sorry I don't know much about VS/Xamarin, but since you are asking about iOS (and maybe have imported the correct frameworks?) in Obj-C you can call NSUUID:

`// Generate an NSUUID object and get its string representation
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] init];
    NSString *key = [uuid UUIDString];
    _itemKey = key;
    NSLog(@"UUID and key is %@", key);`

I put this piece of code in an init for an item object.  This gives me unique UUIDs to operate on them on going forward.  Just correct the syntax for instantiating an object in C#, hope that helps and hope it works!